# Linking class static variable without including whole class declaration

Tags: c++, static

Assume I have a source file A.cpp:

```
#include<string>

struct A {
  static const std::string a;
  static const std::string b;
  static const std::string c;
};

const std::string A::a{"1"};
const std::string A::b{"2"};
const std::string A::c{"3"};
```

And want to use `A::b` in another translation unit. The normal way is to divide `A.cpp` into declaration `A.hpp` and definition, include the first.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<A.hpp>

int main(){
  std::cout << A::b << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

That will certainly work, but I want to avoid including the class declaration, ‘cause in my case `A` is huge and has cumbersome dependencies.

Ideally, I want to have something like

```
struct A; 
external const std::string A::m;
```

But that yields the incomplete type error.

It’s possible to rely on linking via other non-class global var.

```
const std::string A::b{"2"};
const std::string* bptr{&A::b};
```

and declare it in another source file as

```
extern const std::string* bptr;
```

That’s proper way but looks a bit ugly for me, because requires to introduce redundant entity.

Another trick that works for me.

```
struct A {
  static const std::string b;
};

int main(){
  std::cout << A::b << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

It looks fine but hacky, it works even for private members. Is it legal? That’s, is there anything that defines such behavior?

Comment: If you take your full class definition (as big as it might be), put it in a header file that you include in a source file as simple as you show the first `main` source file to be, and measure the time to compile the main source file with the included header file, will it be noticeable? If not then your class is small enough to be put into its own header file as it should be, and you don't have to worry about "hacks" and breaking [the one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: First question is whether you really need such a _huge class with cumbersome dependencies_. Good classes follow the _one entity-one responsibility_ principle. If this is your case, you might also want to consider PIMPL idiom to fully separate class API from all implementation details. Maybe (we don't know the details) this would make you header independent of these cumbersome dependencies.

Comment: You could create `std::string const &getBstringFromA();` and define it in `A.cpp`, where the class is known.

Comment: be careful with the wording. There are ongoing efforts to have modules in c++, afaik it will still take time for them to be standardized (or are they in c++20?). What you have there are not modules in C++ terminology

Comment: Some programmer dude, it’s not a definition, it’s declaration. There can be multiple declarations. 
There are not only time but also circle dependencies that I don’t want to resolve. 

Daniel Langr, It's far not design-time. That huge class is already written is not something that I can refactor at the moment. 

Quentin , that can be a good way around, thanks.

User463035818 , ok, translation unit/source.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento The syntax `struct Name { /* members ... */ };` is technically considered a definition. It is not legal to define the same struct in two different ways in different translation units.

Answer (score 1):

The trick you show at the end is probably the worst hack and can backfire hard some day - as it 'shadows' the other definition. There is no "in between" here (besides numerous 'hacks')- either you make the class definition appear in it's entirety or you lift the string definition off the class.

**It looks fine but hacky, it works even for private members. Is it legal?**

Depends on the context, if a third unit ever gets to pull in both you will be back at the original issue. The reason it works for private its another defition and therefore not private to begin with.

Comment: I tried on gcc 5.4. It linked without any special force. But I got you the backfire warning.

Comment: Should have been compile. I guess you realize that the main issue is you will have different definitions, this is a maintance nightmare. You now have a situation where the 2 are not binary compatible, so an otherwise logical cast in another part of the code have the potential of blowing up. There could be other issues as well. So it's path you will not wan't to go down.

Comment: "Is it legal" does not "depend". It violates the ODR (header version).

Answer (score 0):

From the first glance, the last variant looks for me as some sort of black magic. But the more I think why it works the more I consider it’s almost valid.

One definition rule. There are actually two entities to look at: a string and a class.

The string completely follows one definition rule. That confused me. It does not differ much from declaring the same global var in different sources. Linker never has any problem if there are other references to the same definition. Such double declaration does not do anything special but providing two references to the same definition. And, yes, the linker does not care about different access modifiers of different declarations.

One definition rule is violated for the class. In the provided example the difference cannot break anything. But adding a non-static member to one of definition and trying to move an object between translation units with different class definition starts to shoot in the leg.

Technically it’s not that difficult to maintain such two definitions but anyway better to avoid.

And, probably, I'll stick to the solution suggested by Quentin providing accesses via an additional function.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` only has static member variables in it, then you can change `A` from a struct to a namespace (change `struct` to `namespace`, and get rid of the `static` in front of all the variable names).  Then you can split "A.h" into multiple header files so that you can just include the parts you need.  The definitions of all the variables can be in one .CPP file or can be split among several.